# \DeclareUnicodeCharacter not working at all

Tags: input-encodings

The following code should be valid but doesn't compile at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0052}{W}

\begin{document}
RRRR
\end{document}
```

and I get the following error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Cannot define non-active Unicode char value < 00A0.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0052}{W}
                                     
?
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I am using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: LaTeX refuses to redefine characters in the ASCII printable area.

Comment: Is there a way for me to be able to override this?

Comment: you don't want to make the ascii active, it would break command names using this character (R in your case).

Comment: What would be the purpose?

Comment: I would like to scramble some hints for problems in a Caesar cipher, so students don't accidentally spoil themselves.

Comment: Consider defining a command `\Caesar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the code is not valid. The command `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` will refuse to act on codes in the ASCII printable area, which is what the error message says.

There are *very* good reasons for this: if you make `R` active, you won't be able to use any command that contains `R`, except for `\R`.

If you like to live on the razor edge, you can do

```
\catcode`R=13 \def R{W}
```

but don't hold weird error messages against me: I warned you not to do it.